# How to set checkbox checked items, after click submit button

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

My view code is :

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("submit","Security",FormMethod.Post)) 
{ 

@foreach (var item in Model.app_function) 

{ 

 <input type="checkbox" name="Functioncheck" value="@item.app_function_id"/> 
                    @Html.Encode(item.app_function_name)

}

    <input type="submit" value="submit" /> 
}
```

after click submit button checked values are saved into database, but checked values are unchecked.

My controller code is:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ViewResult submit(FormCollection fm)
    {

                string Roleecheck = Request.Form["Functioncheck"].ToString();
                string[] x = Roleecheck.Split(',');
                int a = Convert.ToInt32(x.Length);
                for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
                {
                    int userid = Convert.ToInt32(x[i]);
                    var myEntity = new user_role { role_id = id, user_id = userid, created_date = DateTime.Now, created_by = 1 };
                    UpdateModel(myEntity);
                    am.Add(myEntity);
                }
                am.Save();

return view();

        }
```

Give me some idea for how to set checkbox checked items, after click submit.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks to me like your business logic is poor, but idealy you would iterate over your users and see if a user exist with the function id (if i understand your code correctly) and if so set "checked" in you input field. so <input ..... checked />. If I have misunderstood please try to explain your code and purpose more clearly

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496353/how-to-get-checkbox-values-back-to-view/10521131#10521131